# No metrics returned from Azure VM Scale Set or Azure ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-powershell, azure-vm-scale-set

When I use `Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition` on a valid resourceId, I get no results.

`Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId /subscriptions/{SUB_ID}/resourceGroups/{GroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{Namespace}`
or
`/subscriptions/{SubId}/resourceGroups/{GroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/{ScaleSetName}`
or
`/subscriptions/{SubId}/resourceGroups/{GroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/{ScaleSetName}/virtualMachines/0`

I have verified the Diagnostics Extension is selected in the VM template. Here's the extension details in the VM0 information:
`Id                          : 
/subscriptions/{SubId}/resourceGroups/{GroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{ScaleSetName}_0/extensions/VMDiagnosticsVmExt_vmNodeType0Name
  Name                        : VMDiagnosticsVmExt_vmNodeType0Name
  Type                        : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions
  Location                    : westus
  Publisher                   : Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics
  VirtualMachineExtensionType : IaaSDiagnostics
  TypeHandlerVersion          : 1.5
  AutoUpgradeMinorVersion     : True
  Settings                    : {"WadCfg":{"DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration":{"overallQuotaInMB":"50000","EtwProviders":{"EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration":[{"provider":"Microsoft-ServiceFa
bric-Actors","scheduledTransferKeywordFilter":"1","scheduledTransferPeriod":"PT5M","DefaultEvents":{"eventDestination":"ServiceFabricReliableActorEventTable"}},{"provider":"Microsoft-ServiceF
abric-Services","scheduledTransferPeriod":"PT5M","DefaultEvents":{"eventDestination":"ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"}}],"EtwManifestProviderConfiguration":[{"provider":"cbd93bc2-71e5
-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8","scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter":"Information","scheduledTransferKeywordFilter":"4611686018427387904","scheduledTransferPeriod":"PT5M","DefaultEvents":{"eventDestina
tion":"ServiceFabricSystemEventTable"}}]}}},"xmlCfg":"...","storageAccount":"j3vk3vnhlxaccyharmq6phsa"}
  ProvisioningState           : Succeeded`

Question: Why am I unable to get metrics from any of the items in my subscription and what additional steps can I take to find the problem?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmation from Microsoft that, at least at the moment, Service Bus does not support this command.
You can query SB metrics via the REST API instead, described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn163586.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

For Virtual Machine scale sets, since there is monitoring diagnostics available for scale sets, definitely you would not get any metrics for scale sets.

The applicable metrics for any resource are available only when diagnostics is enabled for that particular resource. As mentioned above, ***Diagnostics*** is **not** supported for **Virtual Machine scale set** as of today, hence you would not get any list of applicable metrics even if you provide a valid resourceId of your scale set.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide any support for the answer you are providing. Any Reference or something.